# How to check whether vtk polydata has cell or point data

Tags: vtk

How do I check whether a `vtkPolyData` has point data or cell data or none?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you can do:

```
poly.GetPointData().GetNumberOfArrays()
poly.GetCellData().GetNumberOfArrays()
```

In C++ you can similarly do:

```
poly->GetPointData()->GetNumberOfArrays()
poly->GetCellData()->GetNumberOfArrays()
```

Note that a vtkPolyData can simultaneously have point and cell data.

Comment: I suspect this wouldn't work if, for example, poly didnt have pointdata. Calling GetPointData() would cause an exception?

Comment: A polydata will always have point data. Anything that derives from vtkDataSet will have a vtkPointData and a vtkCellData.